# mgwt / gwtphonegap advices, feedback, tips

Tags: gwt, cordova, mgwt

I have to develop an application on Android, iOS and Windows Phone by using Phonegap.

I would like to know if someone has already used mgwt / gwtphonegap and have your feedback / advices on these technologies, if you have encountered some blocking issues for example.

I have already developed a Phonegap application in javascript (jquery / jquery mobile) html / css, but now I would know if I could start another one by using only GWT. However I would like to avoid to begin the development and realize 3 weeks later that I'm blocked because of mgwt / gwtphonegap.

Note that I have never developed with GWT but often in Java

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been using mgwt/phonegap only a few months, so I'm definitely not an expert, but so far no major stumbling blocks. I like GWT, as it is well documented, robust and supported, although mgwt is a bit less so. There's an active google forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mgwt. Maybe if you have some more specific question, I or someone on that forum could answer it.